# WPF Custom Control invisible - theme not found?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to build a WPF custom control library to be usable from different WPF software projects. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I created a new project using the WPF custom control library (.NET Framework) template, where I am defining a subclass of a text box:

**CustomControl1.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CCL1
{
    public class CustomControl1 : TextBox
    {
        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
        }
    }
}
```

(Functionality to be added later), the generic.xaml in this project looks like this:

**Generic.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCL1">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And this is the assembly info:

**AssemblyInfo.cs:**

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CCL1")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("CCL1")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2019")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

//In order to begin building localizable applications, set
//<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .csproj file
//inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english
//in your source files, set the <UICulture> to en-US.  Then uncomment
//the NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in
//the line below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.

//[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                     //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                     // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                              //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                              // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I then add this project as a reference to the main project and want to use the custom control in the main window. Like this:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:ccl="clr-namespace:CCL1;assembly=CCL1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="Hello"/>
        <ccl:CustomControl1 Height="20" Text="Hello"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The normal TextBox is just there for comparison. I can see my CustomControl1 class which is a subclass of TextBox in design mode but when I build and start the application it's not there. My searches told me this is because the theme of the custom control wasn't found, in particular this question:
[WPF Custom Controls Are Invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695888/wpf-custom-controls-are-invisible)
tells me that if I add the line detailed in the second answer to the AssemblyInfo then it should work - this line is however already contained in the AssemblyInfo (it is so from the beginning, it's part of the project template) and it makes no difference. I can get it to show by commenting out the static constructor of the custom control but this seems like a brutal hack, I don't want to be constricted to the control's default theme, I want it to work as intended.

The weirdest thing is, a few hours ago this DID work but then suddenly changed to the behaviour I just described. I don't recall having changed anything in particular to bring this about.

Sorry for re-posting a question that was asked before but I just don't see what I am doing different than the answers that were already given...

EDIT: upon re-building again, the custom control is now not even visible in design mode...

Comment: Try to put something in the `Border` in the `ControlTemplate`. Your current template seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample code you provided, the control template has nothing to display. You're setting `Text="Hello"` but you have no `ContentPresenter` and no binding to the `Text` property.

I would suggest extracting the control template for the TextBox and use it as the starting point for your custom control.

Comment: That helped thank you. I also got some good info here: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFControlTemplates.aspx in case anyone is still looking.